# Multiplicity constraint violation EF Code-First

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, eager-loading

i've a problem with using Entity-Framework 6. I've two classes

```
public class LinkableState : Entity
{
    [Required]
    public long LinkableId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(@"LinkableId")]
    public virtual Linkable Linkable { get; set; }
    public long Counter { get; set; }
    public string Debug { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class ProcessInstance : InstanceBase<Process>
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime InstanceStartTime { get; set; }        
    public DateTime? InstanceEndTime { get; set; }        
    public ProcessInstanceState InstanceEndState { get; set; } = ProcessInstanceState.None;
    public virtual ICollection<LinkableState> LinkableStates { get; set; } = new List<LinkableState>();
    public virtual ICollection<LinkableState> LinkableStateTopCounter { get; set; } = new List<LinkableState>(); 
}
```

Within my code i like to change ProcessInstance.LinkableStates like in this example (at this time the elements of reachedStates are detached)

```
using (IDataLayer db = StorageFactory.GetStore())
{
     ProcessInstance ix = db.GetProcessInstance(processInstanceId);
     ix.LinkableStates = reachedStates;
}
```

if the db obejct get's disposed and saved i get the error

> Multiplicity constraint violated. The role
>   'ProcessInstance_LinkableStates_Source' of the relationship
>   'DataLayer.Mssql.DataBase.ProcessInstance_LinkableStates' has
>   multiplicity 1 or 0..1.

I don't know why EF thinks that there is more than 1 relation ? I've checked the EDMX file (reverse from Code-First) which looks like this:

[image: Reverse EDMX]
[image: Db-Entries]

As you can see in the db-entries the key of ProcessInstance_Id (ProcessInstance.LinkableStates) has been nulled even if ID {1, 3} should be set with Process.Id = 1.

This error occured while i switched from

```
Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

to

```
Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

At the Moment i've absolute no idea why this error occurs when i switch from lazy to eager loading. i already tried to clear the list and add the new elements manually like:

```
using (IDataLayer db = StorageFactory.GetStore())
{
    ProcessInstance ix = db.GetProcessInstance(processInstanceId);
    ix.LinkableStates.Clear();
    foreach (LinkableState e in unvisitedStates)
    {
        ix.LinkableStates.Add(e);
    }
}
```

but this does not change anything.

Do you have any ideas how i can fix this problem ?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, seems like I've solved the Problem.

I did two things. First, i've added the InverseProperty Annotation to my classes

```
public class LinkableState : Entity
{
    ...   
    public long? LinkableStatesId { get; set; }
    public long? LinkableStateTopCounterId { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty(@"LinkableStates")]
    [ForeignKey(@"LinkableStatesId")]
    public virtual ProcessInstance ProcessInstanceLinkableStates { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty(@"LinkableStateTopCounter")]
    [ForeignKey(@"LinkableStateTopCounterId")]
    public virtual ProcessInstance ProcessInstanceLinkableStateTopCounter { get; set; }
}

public class ProcessInstance : InstanceBase<Process>
{
    ...
    [InverseProperty(@"ProcessInstanceLinkableStates")]
    public virtual ICollection<LinkableState> LinkableStates { get; set; } = new List<LinkableState>();

    [InverseProperty(@"ProcessInstanceLinkableStateTopCounter")]
    public virtual ICollection<LinkableState> LinkableStateTopCounter { get; set; } = new List<LinkableState>(); 
}
```

and the second thing is that i set the reference Id for LinkableStates by Hand before i save them and check for a already stored version first.

```
foreach (LinkableState e in copy)
{
    LinkableState tmp = db.GetLinkableState(e.Id) ?? e;
    tmp.LinkableStatesId = ix.Id;
    ix.LinkableStates.Add(tmp);
}
```

for now this solved my "Multiplicity constraint violation" error.
Hope this will help someone else faceing this problem.